# ADO.NET vs. WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

What exactly are ADO.NET and WCF? ADO.NET is it obsolete with WCF or is it a part of WCF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADO.NET and WCF serve different purposes. ADO.NET facilitates connections to a database, while WCF allows communication over a channel (thereby potentially replacing web services).

See [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson01.aspx) for an ADO.NET tutorial and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx) for one on WCF.

Answer (score 3):

Complete seperate thing.

ADO.Net :

> ADO.NET provides consistent access to data sources such as Microsoft SQL Server, as well as data sources exposed through OLE DB and XML. Data-sharing consumer applications can use ADO.NET to connect to these data sources and retrieve, manipulate, and update data.

WCF :

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is Microsoft’s unified programming model for building service-oriented applications. It enables developers to build secure, reliable, transacted solutions that integrate across platforms and interoperate with existing investments.

Answer (score 2):

ADO.NET is a library for communication with databases.

WCF is a framework for interapplication communication, typically from a client to an application server.

Answer (score 1):

ADO.net is a database independent object model to deal with DBMS's.  It is coupled to the idea of the relation database.

WCF is a framework for communication amongst systems.  Many WCF application will use ADO to deal with there final backing store.

These are nonindependent technologies that deal with solving different problems.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is technology for creating services. Main difference from simple Web service is wcf service could work with different protocols (http, tcp, netpipes)